# Does anyone know how I can store those in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

```
const tr = document.createElement("tr");
const td = document.createElement("td");
table.appendChild(tr);
td.innerText = "" + new Date().toLocaleDateString("de-Ch");
tr.appendChild(td);
const td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.innerText = object.text;
tr.appendChild(td2);

const td3 = document.createElement("td");
if (object.amount > 0){
    td3.style.color = "rgb(4, 209, 4)";
    td3.innerText = "+";
} else{
    td3.style.color = "red";
}

td3.innerText += object.amount;
tr.appendChild(td3);
const td4 = document.createElement("td");

td4.style.color = saldo < 0 ? "red" : "black";

td4.innerText = saldo.toFixed(2);
tr.appendChild(td4);
```

Basically this code gets ran when I submit a form and it adds a tr and td's to a table which I already have as elementById. My question is, does anyone know how I could store the values, that I input, as localStorage, so that when I refresh, the table with the different rows stays as before and that I can still add more rows? I'd be very thankful for an answer. If there's more information about the code needed, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: You can store every type with [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=de). Just use [`localStorage.setItem(key, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem), then you can access it with [`localStorage.getItem(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object array and add it in localStorage if it is not available.

```
var objectArray = [];
localStorage.setItem("objectArray", JSON.stringify(objectArray))
```

Add objects to the array when form is submitted and update localStorage.

```
var objectArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objectArray"));
objectArray.push(object);

localStorage.setItem("objectArray", JSON.stringify(objectArray));
```

update the table with new rows based on the objects available in the array.

```
var objectArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objectArray"));
```